# Magento 2 , error {"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"address"}}

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

An Error `{"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"address"}}`

This error appears 
while placing an order with a new billing address, even when all field has values/info.

Comment: is that the error message in your logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting quote fixed the issue.
This fixed the issue.